# Nginx proxy server not loading assets

Tags: nginx

I have created a nginx proxy for the main the rails application. The main application is loading all the assets like css ,js , static images and everything. But the proxy server is loading application without any assets. No css,js or any assets.

Following is my **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

  location ~* /(assets|fonts|swfs|images)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

}
```

Could somebody please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: You have `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location`. They are generally mutually exclusive.

Comment: @RichardSmith you were right. I removed the `try_files` and added it inside assets `location` in the end. It worked.